# Regex to keep one choice in square bracket

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex to replace the whole square bracket with the first choice. For example, `[ choice A | choice B ]` I want to replace the previous square bracket as a whole with `choice A`. However, when I have more than one of these brackets:

`[ choice A | choice B ] and choose between [ choice D | choice F ]`

in the same line, all the brackets get replaced by `choice A`. I know it's because I am selecting [0] in my code, but I don't know how to replace each bracket with its respective choice; namely, `choice A` and `choice D`

```
import re
line = "[ choice A | choice B ] and choose between [ choice D | choice F ]"
x = re.findall( r"\[(.*?)\|", line)[0].strip()
line = re.sub(r"\[(.*?)\]", x,line)
print(line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
line = "[ choice A | choice B ] and choose between [ choice D | choice F ]"
line = re.sub(r"\[\s*([^][|]*?)\s*\|[^][]*]", r"\1", line)
print(line) # => choice A and choose between choice D
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/10FEVH) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C2Rcgf/1). The regex matches

- `\[` -  a `[` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^][|]*?)` - Group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern refers to this value): zero or more chars other than `[`, `]` and `|`, as few as possible
- `\s*\|` - zero or more whitespaces and a `|` char
- `[^][]*` - any zero or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]` - a `]` char.